# While using urllib.request to fetch text data from url getting HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, http, urllib

[image]

I am trying to extract text data from URL using urllib library, when I am running for loop for length of the data frame, it is giving result for 2 - 3 iteration and then throwing error HTTPError:
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden.

I also tried user agent but not issue not resolving:

[image]

Comment: Probably the target Server is treating your continuous requests as DoS attack or a Spam Request and hence rejecting it after few tries. You can try adding a random delay (of 1 - 10 secs) between the requests.

Comment: Adding random delay not working....